# How to save to TextField database transformed with visualTransformation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

How to save to `TextField` database transformed with `visualTransformation`?

I have the following code:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
TextField(
    value = text,
    visualTransformation = DateTransformation(),
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number),
    onValueChange = {
        if (it.length < 9) text = it
    }
)
Log.i("DATA",text)
```

the format is `XX/XX/XXXX` but when I send it to the database it loses the format and is `XXXXXXXX`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply same transformations your `VisualTransformation` does using [`filter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/input/VisualTransformation#filter(androidx.compose.ui.text.AnnotatedString)) like this:

```
val visualTransformation: VisualTransformation = remember { DateTransformation() }
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
Button(onClick = {
    val transformedText = visualTransformation.filter(AnnotatedString(text)).text.text
    // save to DB
}) {

}
TextField(
    value = text, onValueChange = { text = it },
    visualTransformation = visualTransformation
)
```

Comment: perfect thank you very much